# Disable the "Not available for your platform" on the addons.mozilla.org

Tags: firefox-addon

Does anybody know how to disable this message and also to disable gray "Download" buttons?

I wanted to download some addons for Android platform from my desktop PC. When I load an addon page in Firefox it doesn't allow me to "Save Link As..." and the button is gray.
I can only do it if I rightclick the button fast, before the site checks the platform and disables the link.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but does this article here help you out: [gHacks.net :: Bypass Firefox’s Blocked: May contain a virus or spyware message](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/11/19/bypass-firefoxs-blocked-may-contain-a-virus-or-spyware-message/) your issue sounds similar to the people posting in the comments section of this article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random example:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/slimsearch/

I am using Firefox and above is for Android and the button is grey and it says: Not available for your platform

Here are a few options:

1. Right-click on the button, "Save Link As...", then save it to your computer
2. Right-click on the button, "Copy Link Location" and then paste it in any download manger (or another browser) to download.
3. If you have [FlashGot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/) installed and have a download manger, ALT + clicking the button will send the link to your download manager.

**Update based on the added info:**
Example: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/close-all-tabs-mobile/

Run the following script in Scratchpad

```
document.querySelector('div.install-wrapper a').classList.remove('concealed');
```

An easier method is to create a bookmark to run the script (I often do that and use Bookmarks toolbar for it)

```
javascript:void(document.querySelector('div.install-wrapper a').classList.remove('concealed'))
```

Comment: Ah i see what he's asking now. No need for another browser or download manager. Just right click and instead of copy link location do "Save Link As" and choose where to save it and voila.

Comment: Well, thanks for the advices. I know about these possibilities. Just wanted to know if there is an option on the site or in the "about:config" for example to disable this platform check.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to add an example page. But what could you say about this one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/close-all-tabs-mobile/? The button doesn't appear as a link so I can't save it.

Comment: I found in the Web Inspector that the <a> link has the "pointer-events: none" style. So the link is unclickable.

Comment: I can disable that style and save the addon or use the link location itself but this is not very comfortable. So it would be cool if there were some site settings to control this button look.

Comment: @mortalis AFAIK, there is no general setting that you can set to enable what you want. You can write a short GreaseMonkey script to enable the button OR run a small script via Scratchpad (I am going to add it to my above post)

Comment: Thanks man. It helped. I know it was a silly question. Just wanted to get some more easiness in the site using...